# Sending an http post request to a login website? (Authorization)

Tags: java, http, authentication, request, authorization

I have two classes:

```
public class ProtectedAuthorizer extends Authenticator {

public String authorizeProtectedUrl(String requestingUrl) {

    Authenticator.setDefault(new CustomAuthenticator());

    StringBuffer sb = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(requestingUrl);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                url.openStream()));

        String in = "";
        sb = new StringBuffer();

        while ((in = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(in + "\n");
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

And this is my second class:

```
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";

    String promptString = getRequestingPrompt();
    String hostname = getRequestingHost();
    InetAddress ipaddr = getRequestingSite();
    int port = getRequestingPort();

    System.out.println(promptString);
    System.out.println(hostname);
    System.out.println(ipaddr);
    System.out.println(port);

    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
}

}
```

I'm trying to authorize myself to this website: https://id.ogplanet.com/login.og
but whenever I call

```
authorizeProtectedUrl("https://id.ogplanet.com/login.og");
```

it doesn't do anything. How do I use these 2 classes to authorize myself to a login page? (Send an HTTP Post Request to the login page).

Comment: Where are you calling getPasswordAuthentication()?

Comment: Isn´t that what I´m supposed to call if I want to authorize myself?

Answer (score 0):

For doing HTTP related stuff, I recommend to use the [Apache HTTP Components Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) library. On the project web site, there a some [examples](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html). Look at the [Form based logon example](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientFormLogin.java). It seems to me, that it matches your use case very well.